# Send a HTTP POST Request(xml data ) using WWW::Curl in perl

Tags: perl, curl, xmlhttprequest, http-post

I want to use `WWW::Curl` instead of `LWP::UserAgent` to send a post request.
 Below is the Code using `LWP::UserAgent` which works fine.

```
my $agent = LWP::UserAgent->new(agent => 'perl post');
push @{ $agent->requests_redirectable }, 'POST';
my $header  = HTTP::Headers->new;
$header->header('Content-Type'  => "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
$header->content_encoding('gzip');
utf8::encode( my $utf8_content = $args{content} );
sinfo $utf8_content;
$error->description($utf8_content);
$error->log;
my $request = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $args{url}, $header, $utf8_content);
my $response = $agent->request($request);
```

I need to rewrite this code using WWW::Curl as Curl is faster than LWP.
   I have tried the below code but it returns me code '35' as response, which 
   means the request is invalid.

```
my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new();

$curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
$curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_URL,$self->uri());
$curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $utf8_content);

my $response;

$curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,\$response);

my $retcode = $curl->perform();
```

The data i pass in the post request ($utf8_content) is a xml string ,sample xml :

```
   <Request>
     <Source>
       <RequestorID Password="PASS" Client="Client" EMailAddress="email@address.com"/>
       <RequestorPreferences Language="en">
         <RequestMode>SYNCHRONOUS</RequestMode>
       </RequestorPreferences>
     </Source>
     <RequestDetails>
       <SearchRequest>
         <ItemDestination DestinationType="area" DestinationCode="XYZ"/>
         </ItemDestination>
       </SearchRequest>
     </RequestDetails>
   </Request>
```

Moreover  the response too will be a xml string which can be retrieved from $response;

Comment: alternative: [keep the LWP interface and use the libcurl engine](http://p3rl.org/LWP::Curl)

Comment: In order to automatically gzip-compress your request, in the LWP version at least, you can add `$request->encode('gzip');` - it'll handle adding the appropriate `Content-Encoding` header too.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, this should work, but doesn't. The problem is that `$utf8_content_gzip` contains a `\0` in the middle and the C API truncates the request body. If this is a bug and not just a misunderstanding of mine how to talk to WWW::Curl, then either have the bug fixed or work around by simply not encoding the request.

```
use utf8;
use strictures;
use Devel::Peek qw(Dump);
use Encode qw(encode);
use HTTP::Response qw();
use IO::Compress::Gzip qw(gzip $GzipError);
use WWW::Curl::Easy qw();

my $utf8_content_gzip;
{
    my $utf8_content = encode('UTF-8', '<root>Třistatřicettři stříbrných stříkaček stříkalo přes třistatřicettři stříbrných střech.</root>', Encode::LEAVE_SRC | Encode::FB_CROAK);
    gzip(\$utf8_content, \$utf8_content_gzip)
        or die sprintf 'gzip error: %s', $GzipError;
}
Dump $utf8_content_gzip;

my $xml;
{
    my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;
    $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_HEADER(), 1);
    $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_URL(), 'http://localhost:5000');
    $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER(), ['Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8', 'Content-Encoding: gzip']);
    $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_POST(), 1);
    $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS(), $utf8_content_gzip);

    my $response;
    $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_WRITEDATA(), \$response);

    my $retcode = $curl->perform;
    if (0 == $retcode) {
        $response = HTTP::Response->parse($response);
        $xml = $response->decoded_content;
    } else {
        die sprintf 'libcurl error %d (%s): %s', $retcode, $curl->strerror($retcode), $curl->errbuf;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thanx for the reply. I tried with and without encoding but still i get the same return code 35. When i dump the HTTP::Response object, the content is null : see below

bless( {
                 '_content' => '',
                 '_headers' => bless( {}, 'HTTP::Headers' )
               }, 'HTTP::Response' );
cant find what causes the error.. but anyways thank you for giving your valuable time on it.

Comment: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html 35 is `CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR`. We need the full error buffer, use the error handling how I did it in the code above.

Comment: below is the description of the error: 
libcurl error 35 (SSL connect error): gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received. 
I think i need to add some extra packages or modules.. hope you can help me!!! Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid this error message is useless. Provide the output of the following command: `openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 </dev/null`, but replace www.example.com with the real hostname from the URL that you want to connect to; 443 is the standard HTTPS port, change it if necessary. [Edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9062121/edit) to add this information.

Comment: hello daxim, by doing openssl s_client -connect URL . i recieve 
getservbyname failure for URL. i tried with different ports too(443 : https,8080 :http). If this means that i cant connect to the URL then as mentioned in the query it works with HTTP::Request and LWP::Useragent. I am not good with the technical side of networking domain.. so please enlighten me on this issue!! Thank You.

Comment: Use the hostname only, not the full URL. If you have a URL `https://www.example.com/foo/bar?baz=23;quux=42#fnord`, the hostname part is `www.example.com`.

Comment: i tried with the hostname too but says getservbyname failure for hostname

Comment: The error message says that the port after the `:` is wrong. Paste the command exactly how you have just run it, do not substitute or obfuscate anything.

Comment: is post fields data always in gzip content? can not we send the hash structure data directly as like in php?

Comment: No, the data not always gzipped.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3);`?